# Syntax error on token ";", , expected Java Programming

Tags: java, android, eclipse, token

I have this error while coding in Eclipse for android:

Syntax error on token ";", , expected

and

Multiple markers at this line

```
- Syntax error on token ")", { expected after this token
- Return type for the method is missing
- Syntax error on token ".", ... expected
- Syntax error, insert ";" to complete FieldDeclaration
```

And I don't really see why I'm having so much trouble figuring what it is. Eclipse only says where there is an error, not why, and its "Quick fixes" never work.
Does anyone know how to fix this, please?

```
 package com.example.apptest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private final String defaut = "Vous devez cliquer sur le bouton « Calculer l'IMC » pour obtenir un résultat.";
  private final String megaString = "Vous faites un poids parfait ! Wahou ! Trop fort ! On dirait Brad Pitt (si vous êtes un homme)/Angelina Jolie (si vous êtes une femme)/Willy (si vous êtes un orque) !";

  Button envoyer = null;
  Button raz = null;
  EditText poids = null;
  EditText taille = null;

  RadioGroup group = null;

  TextView result = null;

  CheckBox mega = null; /*Error here with the semicolon, eclipse wants a ','*/



    envoyer= (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcul); /*Long error here*/

    raz = (Button) findViewById(R.id.raz);

    taille = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.taille);
    poids = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.poids);

    mega = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.mega);

    group = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.group);

    result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

    // On attribue un listener adapté aux vues qui en ont besoin
    envoyer.setOnClickListener(envoyerListener);
    raz.setOnClickListener(razListener);
    taille.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    poids.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

    // Solution avec des onKey
    //taille.setOnKeyListener(modificationListener);
    //poids.setOnKeyListener(modificationListener);
    mega.setOnClickListener(checkedListener);
 }



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: clean and build should work if this code is placed at proper place

Comment: First try Jigar's solution. Then try to put `envoyer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcul);` inside the `onCreate()` and see f it works.

Comment: Can you put your full class code ? Sometimes Eclipse may behave erratically! So don't loose hope. In the posted code, nothing seems wrong(considering R.id.calcul  as valid).

Comment: The problem is somewhere else.  You're missing `{`or `}` somewhere

Comment: Post the whole method.

Comment: I posted the whole thing, thanks everyone

Comment: Ok, my bad, I had the findViewById outside the onCreate as Shobhit said. But now it won't recognise my listeners. It wants me to declare them as variables, how would I do it?

Comment: Please start a new question with your corrected code.  Where have you declared your listeners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra `}` in the middle of your code so your `onCreate` and `onCreateOptionsMenu` are not actually inside your `MainActivity` class

```
 // your other code
   mega.setOnClickListener(checkedListener);
} //<---- End of MainActivity class

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     ...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    ...
    }

}// <--- should be actual end?
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code is floating inside the class without a proper method to hold it. Just put the code within the onCreate or any other method, and the error you get would be resolved.

```
envoyer= (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcul); /*Long error here*/

raz = (Button) findViewById(R.id.raz);

taille = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.taille);
poids = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.poids);

mega = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.mega);

group = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.group);

result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

// On attribue un listener adapté aux vues qui en ont besoin
envoyer.setOnClickListener(envoyerListener);
raz.setOnClickListener(razListener);
taille.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
poids.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

// Solution avec des onKey
//taille.setOnKeyListener(modificationListener);
//poids.setOnKeyListener(modificationListener);
mega.setOnClickListener(checkedListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have something missing.

```
  CheckBox mega = null;

     /***** Something missing here, don't you think? *******/
     // (hint: maybe an onResume() method declaration)

    envoyer= (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcul);
```

Leave a comment if you still can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can not call findViewById without setting content view in android activity. so your code should be

```
 package com.example.apptest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private final String defaut = "Vous devez cliquer sur le bouton « Calculer l'IMC » pour obtenir un résultat.";
  private final String megaString = "Vous faites un poids parfait ! Wahou ! Trop fort ! On dirait Brad Pitt (si vous êtes un homme)/Angelina Jolie (si vous êtes une femme)/Willy (si vous êtes un orque) !";

  Button envoyer = null;
  Button raz = null;
  EditText poids = null;
  EditText taille = null;

  RadioGroup group = null;

  TextView result = null;

  CheckBox mega = null; /*Error here with the semicolon, eclipse wants a ','*/

//move your code from here


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 // paste your moved code here
envoyer= (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcul); /*Long error here*/

    raz = (Button) findViewById(R.id.raz);

    taille = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.taille);
    poids = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.poids);

    mega = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.mega);

    group = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.group);

    result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

    // On attribue un listener adapté aux vues qui en ont besoin
    envoyer.setOnClickListener(envoyerListener);
    raz.setOnClickListener(razListener);
    taille.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    poids.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

    // Solution avec des onKey
    //taille.setOnKeyListener(modificationListener);
    //poids.setOnKeyListener(modificationListener);
    mega.setOnClickListener(checkedListener);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```